# Can someone identify this Brazilian flower?

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

The photo was taken in january 2004, at Parque Estadual do Rio Preto (Black River State Park), in the Cerrado (savanna-like) of northeastern-central Minas Gerais, Brazil.

The plant was herbaceous/shrub, but maybe it was because of its tender age?

[image: flowers]